# Specific grouping elements in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a problem with my SQL task and didn't find any answers yet.

I've got table with this sample data:

| ID | Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 2020-03-02 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-03-21 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-04-14 |
| 1 | 3 | 2020-05-01 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-08-09 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-09-12 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-10-12 |
| 1 | 3 | 2020-12-04 |

All I want to get is:

| ID | Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 2020-03-02 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-03-21 |
| 1 | 3 | 2020-05-01 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-08-09 |
| 1 | 3 | 2020-12-04 |

Some kind of changing value history, but only if the value was changed - when value on new record is the same, get value with min date.
I tried with grouping and row_number, but got no positive results. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

One way to articulate your logic is to say that you want to retain a record when the previous record, as ordered by the date (within a given `ID`), has a *different* value than the current record.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, LAG(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date) LagValue
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ID, Value, Date
FROM cte
WHERE LagValue <> Value OR LagValue IS NULL
ORDER BY Date;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo